# Android: What is the quickest way to find the current location of the device

Tags: android, service, gps, location

I don't need to be too precise. I want to know location can be an area of the user in one country. I tried using the location service getLastKnownLocation with the update through GPS. If the getLastKnownLocation is unknown, the time it take to get the result is quite a bit of time. I am working on the weather application, I don't need to have the street name. Is there another way of getting the result more faster.

Comment: the only way to get a location if getLastKnownLocation returns null is to start a location manager and get the first point returned, nothing else you can do

Comment: Ok thank, i may have to another solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get the last known location for more detail read here [last Known Location](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html)

or you can request a location updates every period of times you set [request locaion updates](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html)

it's pretty straightforward